# Is there a shortcut for switching between panels in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

Eclipse has an MDI structure (Multi Document Interface), so the search panel, the package explorer and the code editor can all be open in one window, but I haven't found a keyboard shortcut for switching between these panels. For example, after I search the code-base, I would love to have a quick shortcut for going back to the code editor.

Answer (score 25):

If I understand your question correct, you are probably looking for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>. Other navigational shortcuts can be found in the menu: Window > Navigation.

Comment: Where do you get those sweet keyboard images from? I look quite the fool with my old fashioned code-style text.

Comment: Simply wrap the Keys with a < kbd > HTML-Tag (without spaces, of course)

Comment: This worked for me.  At first I was put off by the list that pops up, hoping for instantaneous switching.  Similar to behavior of the "Next/Prev Editor".  But if you just tap-tap-tap-release F7 it will do the switch pretty quickly.  Does anyone else occasionally get stuck tho, for example with the Next/Prev Editor, where it **requires you to press Enter** to trigger the switch?  Drives me craazy.  I think it primarily happens if you end up wanting to stay with the place you started from.

Comment: Thanks. This was what I need. Now I can work without touching my mouse :)

Comment: For mac it's CMD + F7

Comment: Works with "IBM Data Studio"!

Answer (score 4):

Not an universal shortcut for going to any panel, but:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

allows you to go back to any Editor (although it's still a little heavyweight for quick editor navigation).

[image: Switch to Editor]

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to switch between perspectives its: `Crtl + F8` and `Ctrl + Shift + F8`. You can go to Help > Key Assist... for a full list of shortcuts (this list will change depending on the active editor etc.).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.

One is how @VonC did it, in an earlier reply; using **CTRL+SHIFT+E** which opens a box containing all the panes with their paths.

The other one is to simply use **CTRL+E**, which will open a pop-up just over your cursor containing the list of panes open. Parse using arrows and **ENTER**