# How can I switch to the other pane of editors in Eclipse with a shortcut?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

If I have two panes, each with a set of editors open, I would like to switch to the other one with a shortcut.
To clarify, I mean something like Emacs's C-x o, (other-window) or sublime's ctr+1, ctr+2.

Comment: did u try ctrl+pgDown..in excel it switches between worksheets. Might work in eclipse.. Just a guess

Comment: ctr+PgDown is only between the editors in one pane. It is indeed a very similar question but does not have an answer to the question I am asking. By the answers there it looks like there is no default short-cut, how could I bind it?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Other `Navigational Shortcuts` can be found in the menu: `Window > Navigation` and you should go to `Help > Key Assist` for a full list of shortcuts.

Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6209097/866571)!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Key Assist is a very helpful overview of the available shortcuts, however I could not find one that I meant there. Ctr+7 switches between windows, but I would like to switch only between the windows with the code. Moreover it thinks of two panes with code as one window. So I cannot switch between these panes.

Comment: Thanks, but Ctr + F6 navigates you to the most resent editor so if you edited most recently in two editors that are in the same pane, it will not go to the other.